# Find the Class Reference Of Genric Type

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

```
@Service
public abstract class MainService<E extends AbstractEntity, R extends MainRepository<E>> {

    @Autowired
    MainRepository<E> repository;

    public E find(long id) throws Exception {
        return this.repository.find(---, id);
    }
}
```

Here is it possible to find the class reference of the generic type **E** to pass through this method as first argument instead of the **---** ...?

My expectation about the implementation is to create a generic call to avoid the repetition of the below code in all service classes.

```
return this.repository.find(Entity.class,id);
```

Comment: Post code as text rather than image.

Comment: You say you want to avoid a call to the repository specifying the entity class, am I right? As long as the repository instance is not typed with the entity type, this is inevitable. In your case, MainRepository seems to have no type argument (I guess the autowiring does not provide a MainRepository instance with that actual entity type as type argument). Than it is inevitable that all services will have to specify the entity class. The services, however, can get the entity class from the class declaration via reflection.

Comment: @AlbertWaninge I have separate service classed for each page. My intension is that i dont want to write methods which doesnt require extra code. such as save/ update of an entity and also getting the object using primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here's an example of doing that:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class Foo {
    public static abstract class Bar<E> {
        public E returnAnE() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            Class e = (Class)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            return (E)e.newInstance();
        }
    }

    public static class Baz extends Bar<String> {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Baz baz = new Baz();
        String s = baz.returnAnE();
    }
}
```

This code will fail with class structures which don't match what we have here, so you should do instance of checks instead of casts, and check array accesses.